# Postgis geometry where condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a table:

```
create table if not exists places(
id bigserial not null constraint places_pkey primary key,
location geography(Point,4326));
```

With one row:

```
INSERT INTO places (id, location) VALUES
  (1, Geography(ST_MakePoint(14.582045, 46.08060333)));
```

I'd like to query the table for the exact location. I can do it like:

```
select * from places where ST_DWithin(Geography(ST_MakePoint(14.582045, 46.08060333)), location, 0);
```

But surely there is more concise way to do it, something like:

```
select *
from places
where location = Geography(ST_MakePoint(14.582045, 46.08060333))
```

Maybe ST_Equals or some other postgis function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need to wrap `ST_MakePoint()` in `Geometry()` that's the default.

There are two things you can do,

1. Check to see if *the* point exists,
2. Check to see if *a* point exists within range.

If you want to do the latter, `ST_DWithin` is super terse. It creates a bugger around the first input, and looks for all things that `ST_Within` the second input.

```
ST_DWithin(geom, geom, radius);
```

What more could you want?

With equality, if you want to test for binary equality `=` works fine. However, you're subject to rounding errors and you need to be just as precise with both of them so you get the same EKWT.

Comment: Ewan thanks for clarification. That was the answer I was hoping for :)